# ERROR Get Multiple API schedule every day timezone Asia Jakarta

Tags: python-3.x, rest, get

I need your help, to find a solution to the error message from my program, I have searched for solutions on Google have not found a solution to my program error.

Hopefully those who help me will find it easy.

```
My Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\Documents\ProjectPustadinKemenhubPython-main\Data Project Jasa Marga Gerbang\File Api ke Json Terbaru\apjson.py", line 134, in <module>
    api_jasamarga_semuagerbang()
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\Documents\ProjectPustadinKemenhubPython-main\Data Project Jasa Marga Gerbang\File Api ke Json Terbaru\apjson.py", line 108, in api_jasamarga_semuagerbang
    schedule.every().day.at("14:16", "Asia/Jakarta").do(  json.dump([requests.get(url,headers=headersdatagerbanglalin).json() for url in datagerbanglalinJan], file, indent=2))
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PUSTIKOM HUB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Screenshot error message:

[image: Error Message]

My screenshot code:

[image: Code]

My file code:

[My file full source code](https://pastebin.com/WtC4iGJk)